# When I request data from my restAPI the value of the fields is lost

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

I have a method which returns all users from my database:

```
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
        System.out.println("Retrieved users: " + users.toString());  // Add this line for logging
        return ResponseEntity.ok(users);
    }
```

When I print the users everything is fine, but when the data is delivered to the frontend the values is lost:

```
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3500/flash/allUsers');
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data) {
          const userInfo = response.data.map((user) => ({
            username: user.username,
            password: user.password,
            email: user.email,
            userID: user.userID,
          }));
          setUsers(userInfo);
          setFilteredUsers(userInfo);
        } else {
          console.log('Error fetching users');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unexpected error occurred: ', error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

When I log the response the payload is a list with the right name for the fields but all the values are null:

```json
[
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null},
{"userID":null,"username":null,"email":null,"password":null}
]
```

I have tried adding log lines to see where the data is lost

Comment: What does the log in `getAllUsers` show? Where's the source of the `User` class?